# How to access context menu in angular-leaflet-directive

Tags: angularjs, dictionary, angular-leaflet-directive

Can you please tell me how do I create and use context menu in angular-leaflet-directive.

I couldnt find it on the documentation

Please give an example for the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Here, check this out:
https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.contextmenu/commit/25c3c5fc7fcacbd9d716f859b9ce80cca2148325

I just had to move my contextmenu options into the map-subobject of the default object.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers, but provide some code examples. Links can disappear.